# SQL Server: JOIN two different queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

sql-server does not have USING function. To join two different tables with multiple select statements we use 'ON' table1.ID = Table2.ID

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT M.ID as MAPID, M.Name, Avg(Distance) 'Avg Road length', Max(Distance)'Max Length'
 FROM MAP 
 inner join ROAD R on M.ID  = R.MapID                      
 GROUP BY M.ID, M.Name) T1


left join

 SELECT *
 FROM
 (SELECT select  R.MapID as MAPID,  R.IDFrom,  R.IDTo 
  from    ROAD R
 group by R.MapID, R.IDFrom, R.IDTo) T2 ON T1.MAPID = T2.MAPID




 -- using (MAPID); (wrong)
```

Comment: Does SQL Server support `JOIN USING`? Try `ON T1.MAPID = T2.MAPID` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
USING (MAPID)
```

with

```
ON t1.mapid = t2.mapid
```

Comment: @marc_s Your better layout is clearer and noted.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't use * in the outer query - specify the specific columns you want for the result.  You could also modify the query and use the first query as the base and OUTER APPLY with TOP 1 to get the other columns.